# Low TC resistors for current measurement

Tags: resistors, current-measurement

I have a back-burner project to take an old bench power supply and retro-fit it with two 4 digit LED displays for current and voltage. The power supply is 3A/30V, so four digits means 3000 count and 12-bit conversions (4096 = 2^12).

I've been trying to design an analogue current measuring block that just has a pair of current shunt resistors with a relay and some range detection circuitry etc. But I've bumped into a weird question about which resistors to use.

Ignoring the range selection, let's assume that I choose resistor and current sense amplifier so that 3A => 3V. Then, in order to get 1mA accuracy, I have a maximum error of 333ppm. Round that down to 200ppm to give the later ADC some headroom. Now, it seems that a reasonable temperature range is maybe 10°C - 30°C, which basically corresponds to "rooms I can function in". The 15°C range from the midpoint then says that, assuming I null out errors correctly, I can have a maximum TC of 13.3ppm/°C.

Even ignoring any errors from the current sense amplifier, I don't think that one can buy such resistors! (Or not easily). Looking hard at Farnell/Digikey/Mouser, I can find a few 20ppm/°C resistors but that's it.

So the question: Have I messed up my calculation horribly? If not, how do people build multimeters...?

Comment: Farnell sell 0.1% resistors that are 10ppm. I bought some yesterday. The common ones are 5ppm, 10ppm, 15ppm and 25ppm.

Comment: Ah, looking again I see that they do but the SMD ones start at 10 ohm and the through hole ones at 5 ohm, which explains why I didn't spot them. Of couse a 5 ohm resistor is not really suitable for a 3A current shunt...

Comment: Have you checked the total error of your ADC? I suspect it is much larger than the resistor error.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of high-precision measurement of anything. Anyways, if you really need that high precision, you should look into adding a temperature sensor, and having calibration tables across the temperature range over which you expect to use the device.

Comment: Joe: No, the "cunning plan" was to build the analogue section first (so I could insert it and carry on using the bench supply!). Connor: Hmm, that seems likely. I think I'll probably add a temperature sensor to the board with analogue out and when I design the ADC/uC/display part I can decide what to do with the information!

Comment: Do you really need 0.04% accuracy on your current monitor?

Comment: Well, no, but my question was more: "Ammeters with far better than 3000 count precision exist. How on Earth do they do it?"

Comment: Without actually knowing, my guess would be manual or auto-scaling.  You don't try to resolve to mA with a 3A range.

Comment: Erm. How do you explain the five digits that display on the knackered old Thurlby 1504 in front of me? Manual or auto-ranging does indeed get a larger *total* range, but this doesn't change how many digits you can sensibly output. Looking at the ranges, it seems they go for a 8192=2^13 count (eg 80u, 800u, ... 800m) for current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is Vishay's *bulk metal foil* resistors.

They have many package configurations available, but the [VCS series](http://www.vishaypg.com/foil-resistors/list/product-63137/) looks good for current sensing applications.

- 2 ppm / C TCR typical
- 0.5% initial tolerance
- 4-terminal configuration
- Much more stable in value after ESD/EOS events, compared to other types.

Pricing and availability will probably drive you crazy. I found a 1 Ohm VCS1625 part at [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/Y08501R00000B9R/Y0850-1.0ACT-ND/2609940) for $16 each. For 3 A you probably need to go to 0.1 or 0.05 Ohm due to the resistor power limit.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Now I've stared at the catalogues for a bit longer, I think I'll use the Welwyn "OAR" series (Open Air Resistor). They have a 20ppm/°C TCR and maybe a twentieth of the price... Thank you (and the other responders) for the help: I really wanted to check that I wasn't just doing something completely wrong since there seemed to be so few viable parts. Now back to the gain trimming...